# Sign panel layout above buttons layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to define a RelativeLayout where an buttons is aligned at the bottom of the screen and also under a Sign panel layout, to avoid overlapping.
But I can't do it.

Could you please explain how i can do this?

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:id="@+id/sigpanel"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_green"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_next"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:shadowColor="#014927"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="2.5"
            android:text="  Next"
            android:textColor="#001B51"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_red"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cancel"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="#014927"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="2.5"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#001B51"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do u mean by Sign panel layout ? What is the expected screen u r trying to build ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code, this is the solution. You Can use this xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sigpanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_panel"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_green"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_next"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:shadowColor="#014927"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="2.5"
            android:text="  Next"
            android:textColor="#001B51"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_red"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cancel"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="#014927"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="2.5"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#001B51"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Although this answer solves the problem faced by the OP but it's always better to highlight what the real problem was or what you fixed in the provided snippet.